# UIBarButtonItem with stretched not tiled UIImage in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I am using the appearance API to customise the look of my UIBarButtonItems.

I currently need to make my buttons look like this:

[image]

In iOS5 you have this method which is what I am using:

```
UIImage *button = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn"]
                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But this tiles the non capped portion of the image instead of stretching which gives me this:

[image]

iOS 6 has a new method

```
resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:
```

Which lets you specify a 'stretch' resize mode but it is not available for iOS5.

How do I make the button stretch rather than tile the centre of the image for iOS5?

Comment: The reason that was added was because it was a needed feature. You can stretch the image entirely in ios5 or you can repeat a part of it over and over again to fill space but stretching a particular part is a new addition as far as I am aware.

Comment: I'm thinking it is just manipulating the UIImage under the hood somehow so I think there would be some sort of manual workaround to achieve the same effect as the convenience method.

Comment: I'm not going to say that there is not since I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't rule out the possibility that ios6 added more than a convenience method to pull off the task. There could very well be additional draw features added behind the scenes that allow things to take place.

Comment: I tried something similar a few months back but ended up settling on using a flat horizontal gradient for my buttons that would be easily repeatable when stretching horizontally.

Comment: Thats my fallback plan ;)

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad thing, the default navigation bar buttons all have horizontal gradients so it blends well with what users expect an apple interface to appear like.

Comment: hmm yeh, i'm thinking even if you could do this it is going to be an ass pain with the back buttons arrow head cap. Stretching the centre in this case will probably give a wonky diagonal shine effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible in iOS5, buttons should always use a horizontal style gradient if they are styled since the image will always be tiled. I ended up changing the gradient direction.

Comment: Yes, it **is** possible, using the old iOS5 method and techniques described in SDK Compatibility Guide. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old and deprecated `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` method for iOS5 if you need stretching:

```
UIImage* (^makeStretchableImage)(UIImage*, CGSize) = nil;
if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:)])
{
    // If resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode: is available, use it
    makeStretchableImage = ^(UIImage* image, CGSize inset) {
        return [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset.height, inset.width, inset.height, inset.width) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    };
}
else
{
    // Else, we are on an older iOS release, use the deprecated iOS5 method instead
    makeStretchableImage = ^(UIImage* image, CGSize inset) {
        return [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:inset.width topCapHeight:inset.height];
    };
}

UIImage* stretchableImage1 = makeStretchableImage(originalImage1, CGSizeMake(5,2));
UIImage* stretchableImage2 = makeStretchableImage(originalImage2, CGSizeMake(15,4));
UIImage* stretchableImage3 = makeStretchableImage(originalImage3, CGSizeMake(8,5));
```